# How do I use a file opened by GUI in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, arcgis, shapefile, arcpy

I have these lines of code:

```
import tkFileDialog, arcpy, arcpy.da, numpy as np, Tkinter
import arcpy.mapping as mapping

fc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('shapefiles','*.shp')],title='Choose a Shapefile')
print 'fc = {0}'.format(fc)
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

#Find the number of rows(alternatives) and print it!
number_of_rows = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
R = int(number_of_rows.getOutput(0))
print R
#Find the number of columns(criterias) and print it!
C = len(arcpy.ListFields(fc))
print C
```

It creates a GUI where I can browse and open a shapefile.
This shapefile is an ArcMap shapefile with a layer and an attribute table.
With this algorithm I get this error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open
>   C:/Users/Th/Desktop/waterways.shp
>
> Failed to execute (GetCount).

How can I solve this?
Without using the GUI, I manually add to the algorithm the shapefile:

```
fc = "C:/Users/Th/Desktop/waterways.shp"
```

Comment: You are getting an ArcPy error so I think your question would be better researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I ran your code without error in ArcCatlog. You will need to provide more details on how you are executing this script. Make sure your file is not open or being locked by another application